# UPDATE ISSUE SNAP STORE

Tags: snap, snap-store

[**screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDRgH.png)

Kindly I am a newbie to UBUNTU,I request assistance to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you open a terminal and try running `sudo snap refresh`?

Comment: Quit Snap Store first (Ctrl+Q to Quit -- don't merely close or minimize the window) . Snap Store cannot refresh while it is running. Then run `sudo snap refresh`. Wait for the command to complete; be patient. Then you are free to restart Ubuntu Software (a.k.a Snap Store)

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate to each of you.